# Referral Broadcast Receiver is not receiving

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hello I am working on android where I am using `INSTALL_REFERRER` for tracking source and medium and marketing purpose and pay users some funds when they come from particular source.

So this is very important for the app but currently it's works 50% cases but doesn't work almost 50%. I failed to find out the why it's behaving weird.

I believe everyone has updated Google Play Version 5.x.xx.

This is how I am doing. I've already read my threads on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me. :(

```
<receiver
    android:exported="true"
    android:name="com.example.InstallReferrerReceiver" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some of the code of your `onReceive` method, or at least describe what you do there? How have you verified that it doesn't get called? could it be that you are doing a long operation that just does not finish?

Comment: @Muzikant I am calling one web service but that's in asynctask. should not we do asyntask in it ?

Comment: You should not start an `ASyncTask` within the `onReceive` method. I added an answer with a detailed explanation and a suggestion to resolve the issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/28235795/624109

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on the response to the comment on the question - `BroadcastReceiver` is not meant to execute any long operation, as it terminates quickly (This is why you get ~50% success rate - it **sometimes** works, but not designed for it).

Read more on the `Receiver Lifecycle` section at the [`BroadcastReceiver` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) - specifically, the following quote:

> anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available,
>   because you will need to return from the function to handle the
>   asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no
>   longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before
>   the asynchronous operation completes.

I suggest you use an `IntentService` so that in your `onReceive` you call the `startService` method to start an `IntentService` that in its `onHandleIntent` method you perform the actual call to the web service.

You can use the `Intent` you use to call `startService` to provide the `IntentService` with the info from the `BroadcastReceiver`.